# Using tuckey, remove all query string paramerers from the url when a particular parameter exists

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I just got introduced to tuckey and was playing around with rewriting url query parameters in a pentaho server (spring).

What I am trying to do:
Rewrite

```
http://hostname:8080/pentaho/api/repos/:public:Steel%20Wheels:Regional%20Sales%20%28dashboard%29.xdash/viewer?token=ABC-1234-42rheRFrhewu2425-ticket&username=popcorn
```

TO

```
http://hostname:8080/pentaho/api/repos/:public:Steel%20Wheels:Regional%20Sales%20%28dashboard%29.xdash/viewer
```

Things that didn't work for me:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/viewer$</from>
    <to type="redirect" last="true">/viewer</to>
</rule>

<rule>
    <condition type="parameter" name="token" operator="equal">(*)</condition>
    <from>^/viewer$</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">viewer</to>
</rule>
```

and many variants. checked old posts also. I know I could be either doing something wrong with regex or the configuration is completely off. any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot completely about this questions since no one responded. Answering myself in case some one finds themselves in same position.

```
<rule>
    <condition type="parameter" name="token" operator="equal">(*)</condition>
    <from>^/viewer(.*)$</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">viewer</to>
</rule>
```